# Fastest python/C++ multimedia library

Tags: c++, python, opengl, multimedia

I'm using pyglet for my OpenGL based game but is it the fastest library out there which has a python wrapper? I could create a C++ extension and use any C++ multimedia library. Are there any C++ libraries that are worth investing time into or is it not worth the extra work?

Thank you.

Comment: The main ones are PyGame and Pyglet. Assuming you're working on a game, if you're worried about speed that much, I wouldn't put your rendering logic in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/) is a python wrapper for the [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) library, which is widely used in game developing and provides OpenGL, sound and input management. To my knowledge at least SDL is quite fast, and the wrapper just encapsulates the binary functionality for python usage. Depending on your usage you can accomplish high speed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say [(Py)SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) but I'm not sure of what your multimedia requirements are.